# selecting from different mysql db tables

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have two tables in my db, TBMEMBERS & TBCOUPON. The first table got two fields "`Id` (auto increment) & `member`"  the other is "`coupon_code`".

What I want is a situation where I have to input member and coupon_code via a form and it will check if the member & coupon_code exist it the respective tables. If it does it will login and display the details.

I have the below lines of code but I keep on getting the "member not exist error"

**tbmembers**

```
    Id                Member    
    1                 Taylor
    2                 Connor
```

**Tbcoupon**

```
    Coupon_code
      12345
      54321
```

My code:

```
 $sql = "SELECT member, coupon_code
                    FROM tbmembers,
        tbcoupon
                    WHERE member = '" . $formfield1 . "' OR coupon_code = '" . $formfield2 . "';";
            $result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

            // if this user exists
            if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1) {

                // get result row (as an object)
                $result_row = $result_of_login_check->fetch_object();


                    // write user data into PHP SESSION
                    $_SESSION['member'] = $result_row->member;

                    $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;

                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = "Wrong coupon_code. Try again.";
                }
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "This user does not exist.";
            }
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = "Database connection problem.";
        }
    }
}
```

I know a match is needed between the tables, but in this situation any member can pick up any coupon_code so no coupon_code is linked to a particular member.

Is my intention not possible with mysql & php?

Comment: I am not an sql expert but I think in this instance you need to prepend the column with the table like so: `"...WHERE tbmembers.member = '$formfield1' ..."`. Something like that. I could be wrong but I think I have used this method before and that is what I had to do.

Comment: Is there more code above this because you have more if statements it looks like but we can't see what the conditions are for them. You say you get the user does not exist error, but the if statement is missing from this code. That would be helpful.

Comment: gentledozy I wouldn't recommend you parse your parameters in the query like that.. its usually vulnerable to sql injection... have you looked into parametric queries? and also you shouldn't use the preANSI way of joining tables... there isn't any meaningful connection between the member and the coupon from what i can see which could be bad....

Comment: @ jonhrudell that's my point in this question since any member can pick up any coupon_code the tables are not related in any way

Comment: @ Rasclatt I know the error is due to the two tables not having any link. I am asking if there is a way around that.

Comment: Read up on JOINS => http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: There's a question that came up http://stackoverflow.com/q/26303833/ - See the given answer(s) in there (*it's a basic example of a `JOIN`*). You can then further your research on "mysql data in two tables", where you will find many results. You basically need to have a matching reference for both tables.

Comment: @Fred-li please read my question again.
I said any member can pick up any coupon_code. How can I link both tables then?

Comment: Arshad's answer didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this(according to your question) :

```
"SELECT member, coupon_code
 FROM tbmembers, tbcoupon
 WHERE member = '" . $formfield1 . "'  AND coupon_code = '" . $formfield2 . "' ";
```

and your if condition should be:

```
if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows > 0){
    //get result, set login status as 1 etc
} else{
   //Wrong coupon code or user does not exist error
}
```

Comment: @Gentledozy: let me know the code worked for u or not :)

Comment: thank you I will get back to you if it works or not. can u up vote that question?