# MySQL select from table depending to other table values

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am sorry for disturbing, but I need little help from you professionals...

I have two tables:

```
Table1:
ID, date, menu1, menu2, menu3, menu4
```

and

```
Table2:
ID, name, somethingElse, somethingElse2
```

In Table1 (menu1, menu2, menu3, menu4) are IDs of Table2. What I need is query "date" value to database and get four rows from Table2 (depending on menuX values of Table1) Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1):

Read the MySQL-docs and look in a MySQL-Tutorial on JOINing. There you will find something like this:

Do a simple `SELECT` spiced up with a `JOIN` and tell MySQL to use `ID` as join-colum:

```
SELECT Table1.`date` FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE Table1.menu1 = "someValue"
AND Table1.menu2 = "someOtherValue"
```

If this runs a bit slow try adding an `INDEX` on one of the tables id-col:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD INDEX myIndex (ID)
```

You can check how many rows are examined by stating

```
EXPLAIN SELECT Table1.`date` FROM Table1 ...
```

Comment: Table1.ID != Table2.ID there is no connection. Table1.menu1 = Table2.ID, Table1.menu2 = Table2.ID, Table1.menu3 = Table2.ID, Table1.menu4 = Table2.ID, this is what I need, get four rows from Table2 by querying date which is in Table1

Comment: So what? Just use these conditions in `ON` Part of the query above. Connect them by `AND`...

Comment: But in your example is not place to add "WHERE `date`='14-10-10'" I need something like SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.ID =

Comment: But in your example is not place to add "WHERE `date`='14-10-10'" I need something like
$date = '14-10-10';
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.ID = Table1.row_where_date_=_$date.menu1_column_value AND Table2.ID = Table1.row_where_date_=_$date.menu2_column_value AND Table2.ID = Table1.row_where_date_=_$date.menu3_column_value AND Table2.ID = Table1.row_where_date_=_$date.menu4_column_value

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I understand your question. Thanks to your provided examples here is a query that should solve your Problem. The trick here is to use a `UNION` to append one query result under another. Doing this four times will do the trick:

```
SELECT b.* FROM dailymenu as a JOIN menu as b ON a.menu1 = b.ID WHERE a.`date` = '2014-10-08'
UNION
SELECT b.* FROM dailymenu as a JOIN menu as b ON a.menu2 = b.ID WHERE a.`date` = '2014-10-08'
UNION
SELECT b.* FROM dailymenu as a JOIN menu as b ON a.menu3 = b.ID WHERE a.`date` = '2014-10-08'
UNION
SELECT b.* FROM dailymenu as a JOIN menu as b ON a.menu4 = b.ID WHERE a.`date` = '2014-10-08'
```

Your menu sounds very tasty :-)

Comment: Maybe sounds, but it isn't :-D It's menu from factory's kitchen and this project is here only for reporting to HQ, how bad is situation :-D -> Employes are rating food :-)